# SQL Query to split 1 value into 3 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My requirement is like. I have 3 column & 1 row.

```
Column A -> Value a
Column B -> Value b
Column C -> Value 123
```

I have to split value in column C and get 3 rows from that, and also copy values from another columns. I have to get 3 rows and it should be like:

```
Column A -> Value a , a , a
Column B -> Value b , b , b
Column C -> Value 1, 2, 3
```

Any Idea?

Comment: search 'pivot clause'. That will help you a bit and give you an idea from where to start. Also, what sql-server version are you using?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using SQL Server 2012...

Comment: good, pivot clause is soported since 2005, I think..

Comment: @ElVieejo - I don't think that this has anything to do with `PIVOT` at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
create table test(cola varchar(10),colb varchar(10),colc varchar(10))

insert into test select 'a','b','123'


    ;WITH CTE AS(
    select cola,colb,LEFT(colc,1) colc,RIGHT(colc,len(colc)-1) as rem from test
    union all
    select cola,colb,LEFT(rem,1) colc,RIGHT(rem,len(rem)-1) as rem from CTE
    where LEN(rem) >= 1
    )
    select cola,colb,colc from CTE
```

Comment: +1 - This works fine, but I would add the clause `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 100)` or some other value at the end of your query

Comment: What if the lenght of the values in columnC is more than 100?

Comment: That was only an example. Actually, if you don't add that hint, the default value is 100, so your current query is limited to that. If you don't want a limit to the recursion level, then you need to add `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)`